# R code: quickly finding the pattern & its repeats within a vector of string

Tags: r, algorithm

I am having a vector of numbers, whereby I would like to analyze them as characters. For each set of number (i.e. "3412123401234"), I would like to know what is the pattern, prioritizing the one that occurred most often with the pattern length more than 1. In the case of the "3412123401234", I would like it recognize "34" as the pattern and the occurrence as 3.

I have a very inefficient algorithm, that takes forever to cycle a list of 100000+ number sets. Need a much more efficient way in handling it in a vector manner.

```
repeats = function(string){
  out = c()
  check.till = floor(nchar(string)/2)
  for (start in 1:nchar(string)){
    for (end in 1:check.till){
      pat = substr(string,start,start+end)
      repeats = length(gregexpr(pat,string)[[1]])
      length = nchar(pat)
      if (length >= 2) out = rbind(out, c(pat, repeats, length))
    }
  }
  out = as.data.frame(out, stringsAsFactors = F)
  colnames(out) = c("Pattern","Repeats","Pat.Length")
  out$Repeats = as.integer(out$Repeats)
  out$Pat.Length = as.integer(out$Pat.Length)
  out = out[out$Repeats > 1,]
  out = out[order(out[,2],out[,3],decreasing = T),]
  out = out[1,]
  out[is.na(out)] = 0
  return(out)
}
```

Comment: When I tried your function, it output "pattern" 34 with repeats=3 (whereas your question wanted "1234" as the pattern with occurence as 2"). Which one is the desired answer? Any additional constrains on the length of the pattern?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I am sorry, I wrote the question wrongly. I do want to prioritize the number of repeats then the length of the pattern. will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Note: Besides "34" the pattern "12" also appears 3 times. Furthermore, if "1234" appears `n` times: then "12","123","23","234","34" all appears `n` times as well. So you might just as well search for "xx" patterns since these will always occur more often.

Comment: actually the identification of the number is for checking purposes only, I am just needing to obtain the attribute of Length and the number of Repeats.

Comment: Can the person downvoting all answers at least comment on why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this is a solution, but what I tried is to split the vector in all unique combinations.

My idea was that all combinations are included in the upper half of a "diagonal-matrix":

```
d <- c("3412123401234")
# create function
make.matrix <- function(x,y) {
 vl <- nchar(d)
 OUT <- seq(x,nchar(y),1)
 if(length(OUT) < vl) OUT <- c(OUT,rep(NA,vl-length(OUT)))
 OUT
}
mm <- sapply(1:nchar(d), make.matrix, d)  
mm

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
tmp    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13
tmp    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11    12    13    NA
tmp    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13    NA    NA
tmp    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13    NA    NA    NA
tmp    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp    8    9   10   11   12   13   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp    9   10   11   12   13   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp   10   11   12   13   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp   11   12   13   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp   12   13   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
tmp   13   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Now I split the vector with the `str_sub` function of the `stringr` package based on the start values of the first row with each other row of the matrix `mm`

```
library(stringr)
mm2 <- sapply(2:nrow(mm), function(x,y) str_sub(string= y, start= mm[1,], end= mm[x,]), d)
```

Finally the count of the unique patterns:

```
counts <- sort(table(mm2),decreasing = T)
```

Your desired output:

```
res <- data.frame("nlength"=sapply(names(counts),nchar),"counts"=counts)
head(res)
     nlength counts
12         2     3
34         2     3
123        3     2
1234       4     2
23         2     2
234        3     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach in base R (not really far from your actual algorithm, mainly using a regex to get the possible matches of length 2 at minimum):

```
str<-c("3412123401234") # example entries

replength<-function(pat,s) {
  length( gregexpr(pat,s)[[1]] )
}

repeats<-function(s) {
  r<-sapply(
    unique(
      regmatches( s, gregexpr("(\\d{2,})(?=.*\\1)", s, perl=T) )[[1]]
    ),
    replength,s=s )
  pat<-names(r[r==max(r)][1])
  data.frame("Pattern"=pat,"Repeats"=unname(r[r==max(r)][1]),"Pat.length"=nchar(pat),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
```

This give as output:

```
> repeats(str)
  Pattern Repeats Pat.length
1      34       3          2
```

It will skip some intermediate matches, `123` in first example, depending on how they appear in the string. However, if they're not matched it should be that they are 'superseded' by another match longest or equivalent (I didn't found a test case proving it wrong).

Benchmark of answers (The code is quite long with all functions so I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Tensibai/b06c81ece98c34c6099a) of it):

```
> microbenchmark(original(str),jimbou(str),tensibai(str),times=3)
Unit: microseconds
          expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 original(str) 1439.982 1722.5050 1849.559 2005.028 2054.347 2103.667     3
   jimbou(str) 1866.474 1994.3365 2227.586 2122.199 2408.142 2694.086     3
 tensibai(str)  468.971  494.9145  558.109  520.858  602.678  684.498     3
```

Answer (score -1):

As others have noted, a 2-gram pattern will always be at least tied for the most common, so it (almost) suffices to consider 2-grams only.*

Just for fun, consider this python 3 solution:

```
# Solution
from collections import Counter
def most_common_2gram(row):
    pairs = [tuple(row[j:j+2]) for j in range(len(row)-1)]
    return Counter(pairs).most_common(1) # or most_common(k) as desired

# Testing Data
from random import randint
nrow = int(1e6)
ncol = 10
x = [[randint(0,9) for j in range(ncol)] for i in range(nrow)]

# Performance Test
%timeit [most_common_2gram(row) for row in x]

# Time result: 21 seconds (from %paste into IPython)
```

Example run with 20 columns:

```
x[0:5]
Output: 
 [[0, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 3, 8, 5, 1, 5, 4, 7, 8, 5, 4, 2, 3, 5],
 [6, 5, 4, 0, 9, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 7, 1, 7, 0, 7, 5, 1, 9, 0, 5],
 [2, 4, 8, 5, 8, 9, 5, 9, 0, 8, 8, 2, 4, 8, 1, 6, 3, 7, 8, 1],
 [5, 6, 6, 7, 1, 7, 9, 3, 3, 0, 7, 9, 5, 7, 6, 3, 8, 5, 3, 3],
 [4, 6, 3, 9, 1, 5, 5, 4, 9, 0, 2, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5]]

out[0:5]
Output: [[((5, 4), 2)], [((9, 0), 2)], [((4, 8), 2)], [((3, 3), 2)], [((1, 5), 2)]]
```

If you want all patterns, not just the most common, you can convert the Counter object to a list and sort by count. For example:

```
counts = Counter({(0,2): 2, (3,4): 3, (1,6): 1})
sorted(counts.items(),key=lambda pc: pc[1],reverse=True)
Output: [((3, 4), 3), ((0, 2), 2), ((1, 6), 1)]
```

*The only possible exception would be if there's a 3-gram (or more) of equal frequency to the 2-gram and you want the 3-gram+ to be preferred. This situation can be detected and handled by a more complex code.